# PHP - Create name attributes for input appending an incrementing number

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have this array of which I am using to create a UI component. The plugin that I'm using requires unique names to be passed into the `name="<name>"` attribute of an input. Naturally I'd like to pass the `broadcast`, `direct_response` and so on as seen below.

```
  'Marketing' => array( 
    'broadcast' => 4, 
    'direct_response' => 5, 
    'events' => 8, 
    'print' => 5,
    'out_of_home' => 3, 
    'online' => 7, 
    'social_media' => 5, 
    'sales_promotion' => 4 
    ),
```

The issue I'm running into is that the UI components will be repeated multiple times based for multiple times. This causes an issue because the `name` attribute's are not unique, therefore I need to append an arbitrary value such as an incrementing number such as `broadcast-0` and `broadcast-1` at the end (repeated for all `keys`).

I can determine the number of times it will repeat with the variable called `$marketCount`. Right now this is simply a value such as `4`, not an array.

```
<?php foreach ($profile['Marketing'] as $name => $value): ?>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$name)) ?></td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $name ?>" class="star {split:2} required" value="0.5" />
      <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $name ?>" class="star {split:2} required" value="1.0" />
      <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $name ?>" class="star {split:2} required" value="1.5" />
      <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $name ?>" class="star {split:2} required" value="2.0" />
      <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $name ?>" class="star {split:2} required" value="2.5" />
      <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $name ?>" class="star {split:2} required" value="3.0" />
      <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $name ?>" class="star {split:2} required" value="3.5" />
      <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $name ?>" class="star {split:2} required" value="4.0" />
      <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $name ?>" class="star {split:2} required" value="4.5" />
      <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $name ?>" class="star {split:2} required" value="5.0" />
    </td>
  </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So what I need to do is append something to the `<?php echo $name ?>` that will produce values such as `broadcast-1` so that I have multiple different groups.

Let me know if I'm missing anything in my explanation.

Comment: if you don't mind the sequence, you could just initialize a counter above the looop, then increment it everytime, then just append `echo $name.($value+$counter)`, like that, and why do you want this? you could just use `values[$name][]` instead

Comment: Would the counter simply be `$counter = 0;` before the `foreach()` or do I need more?

Comment: yes just initialize in top, why do you need to do this? i suggest just create a grouping array instead, its much easier to manage that way

Comment: That worked. The reason is due to a UI component I'm using. I have multiple modals that when you open represent some rating data, the javascript when the name's are the same puts all of each modals data into the first one. So I need to unique the names that they get placed in their proper modals. 

If you want to show me how the grouping array works, I'm open to see that as well. Always looking for best and most performant code.

Comment: where does `0.5, 1.0, 1.5` came from anyway? is that just hardcoded, anyway, i haven't decided to answer the question, still doesn't quite understand the whole context

Comment: I'm using this [Star Rating](https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/) plugin where I'm representing a value between 0.5 - 5 and it will show half stars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still unclear why do you need a naming convention like that, but yes it is possible to do something like that. Simplify it like this:

```
<table>
<?php $i = 0; foreach ($profile['Marketing'] as $name => $value): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$name)) ?></td>
    <td>
    <?php foreach (range(0.5, 5.0, 0.5) as $index => $val): ?>
      <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $name.($value+$i); ?>" class="star {split:2} required" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" />
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I know it's a bit hard to explain. I need the unique naming because without it, the jQuery plugin breaks and places content from all of the app into one single place. Basically I'm fighting that issue. Going to make a small edit to your code I needed to get it to work.

Comment: @dvoutt yes i edited it to fit into `broadcast-0` something like that, well if this works for it, im glad it did

Comment: @dvoutt yes i've checked the plugin, kinda odd to follow that kind of naming convention

Comment: I didn't need to with another part of the app, but this current part where I'm implementing presented me this new problem.

Comment: Thanks. I actually changed the echo out a little bit only because I realized the math could make two numbers that would collide and group. `<?php echo $name.'-'.$value.'-'.$counter; ?>` .. just for anyone reading later.